# Как сделать кнопку картинкой?

Tags: html, css, button

```
function wo_item_button() {
  $itemId = osc_item_id();
  $item = Item::newInstance() - > findByPrimaryKey($itemId);
  if ($item) {

    if (!ModelWo::newInstance() - > premiumFeeIsPaid($item['pk_i_id']) && osc_get_preference('but_premium', 'wo') == 1) {
      $category_fee = ModelWo::newInstance() - > getPremiumPrice($item['fk_i_category_id']);
      if ($category_fee > 0) {
        Walletone::button($category_fee, sprintf(__("Premium fee for item %d", "wo"), $item['pk_i_id']), $item['pk_i_id'], 1, __("Make Premium", "veronika"));

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Как сделать, чтобы `button` была картинкой?

МНЕ НАДО Отдельный стиль типа для этой кнопки
когда пишу Walletone::button2 выдает ошибку

Comment: вы серьезно думаете, что тэги `html`, `css` и `button` являются самыми нужными в этом вопросе?

Comment: ну, был бы я профи, не писал бы сюда.

Comment: вы, очевидно, используете какой-то фреймворк или библиотеку в вашем пхп коде. Вот название этой штуки и должно фигурировать в вопросе и тэгах.

Comment: @teran , имхо, тут надо удалить код из вопроса, а теги оставить.